# Allocating memory for multiple buffers including alignment

Tags: c++, alignment

I'd like to allocate memory for contiguous arrays of several different types. That is, like this, but with dynamic sizes:

```
template <typename T0, std::size_t N0, typename T1, std::size_t N1, ...>
struct {
    T0 t0s[N0];
    T1 t1s[N1];
    ...
};
```

Naively, the size is just `sizeof(T0) * N0 + sizeof(T1) * N1 + ...` but alignment makes it tricky, I think. You'd align the whole thing on `alignof(T0)`, then after `N0` `T0`s, you have to figure out the `alignof(T1)` spot to start the `T1`s. There's `std::align` for this, but it's geared toward finding where to put them after you already have memory allocated, so it would take a little effort to use it before allocating memory.

**Is there some easy off-the-shelf way to calculate the size and offsets of a dynamic struct like this?** I'm picturing a function like

```
// Return the offsets in bytes of the ends of each array
template <typename... Ts>
std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> 
calculateOffsets(const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> sizes);
```

for example:

```
auto offsets = calculateOffets<char, float>({3, 2});
// Offsets is now {4, 12} because the layout is [cccXffffFFFF] where c is a char, X is padding, f and F are the two floats.
// Now we can allocate a buffer of size offsets.back() with alignment alignof(char) and placement-new 3 chars starting at buf + 0, and 2 floats at buf + offsets.front()
```

It's funny because clearly the compiler has this logic built in, since at compile time it knows the layout of the above struct when the sizes are static.

(So far I'm only interested in POD types; to work fully generically I'd additionally need to deal with exception-safe construction and destruction.)

Comment: [`std::offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) but I'm not exactly sure how you would use it since you would need to know the name of all the class members.  I suppose you could switch to having a `std::tuple` of arrays instead of individual member array to make that easier.

Comment: If your arrays are "dynamic" in size, does that a more realistic illustration is that the struct would contain several pointers to each contiguous sequence? If so, you could always allocate with the highest alignment of all the types and then assign pointers by winding down in size of alignment. This would make use of the fact that an object aligned at a 16-byte boundary is also aligned at an 8-byte boundary, etc

Comment: You do not provide background to the question - so it could be an X/Y question for all we know - what are you really trying to solve ? You could build a table of sorts at compile-time using templates, etc. then extrapolate alignment from there with a loop, just a thought. Or you could switch design and use a common alignment that fits well on target machine - then manually align your stuff on some unaligned memory.

Comment: Also just because the compiler has this logic built, doesn't mean it should be exposed or even that it is straightforward to do so.

Comment: I don't have a particular problem I *need* to solve, I just was surprised to find that something that the compiler can do trivially didn't seem to have a library equivalent. I was looking to avoid two allocations yet have contiguous memory (I.e., I could allocate a buffer of `std::pair<T0, T1>`s), but then iterating over the `T0`s isn't trivial.

Comment: @Ben but then why you cannot just use unaligned memory ? unless you need packing, which it sounds exactly like you dont. Also these days there is 'buffering' at the program/c++ level for normal allocations so not every little allocation goes through the OS: so maybe premature optimization ?

Comment: @Ben Have you also noticed that there is no library call that would turn source code into assembly even though the compiler can do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in facilities for this -- but this is a solvable problem in C++.

Since what you're effectively looking for is a "packed buffer" of aligned contiguous components, I would recommend doing this by allocating the sum of all buffers at the alignment of the *most aligned object*. This makes calculation of the length of the buffer in bytes easy -- but requires remapping of the order of the data.

The thing to remember with alignment is that a 16-byte boundary is also aligned to an 8 byte boundary (and so on). On the other hand, it is not true that 4 bytes from an 1-byte boundary will be on an 4-byte boundary<sup>1</sup>. It *may be*, but this depends on the initial pointer.

#### Example

As an example, we want the following in the buffer:

- 3 `char`s (`c`)
- 2 `float`s (`f`)
- 2 `short`s (`s`)

We assume the following is true:

- `alignof(float) >= alignof(short) >= alignof(char)`
- `sizeof(float)` is `4`
- `sizeof(short)` is `2`
- `sizeof(char)` is `1`

For our needs, we would want a buffer that is `sizeof(float) * 2 + sizeof(short) * 2 + sizeof(char) * 3` = `15` bytes.

A buffer that has been sorted by the alignment would look like the following, when packed:

```cpp
ffff ffff ssss ccc
```

As long as the initial allocation is aligned to `alignof(float)`, the rest of the bytes in this buffer are guaranteed to be suitably aligned as well.

It would be ideal if you could just arrange your data to always be in descending order of alignment; but if this is not guaranteed to be the case, you could always use a pre-canned template-metaprogramming solution to sort a list of `T...` types based on the `alignof(T)` for each object.

---

<sup>1</sup> The issue with your suggestion of aligning in order of the buffers is that a situation like `alignof(char)`, which is `1` byte, does not guarantee that `3` `char`s later and `1` padding byte from the initial alignment is aligned to a `4` byte alignment. A pointer of `0x00FFFFFE01`  is "1-byte aligned", but 4 bytes later is `0x00FFFFFE05` -- which is still unaligned.

Although this may work with some underlying allocators, like `new`/`std::malloc` which have a default alignment of `alignof(std::max_align_t)` -- this is not true for more precise allocation mechanisms such as those found in `std::polymorphic_allocator`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some easy off-the-shelf way to calculate the size and offsets of a dynamic struct like this?

There is no such function in the standard library. You can probably implement it using `std::align` in a loop.

Comment: That's my thought. I think I could write `uintptr_t intAlign(size_t alignment, size_t size, uintptr_t& offset)` based on `std::align` with unbounded `space` and starting with an `offset` of `alignof(T0)`, then subtract off the `alignof(T0)` from the result.

Comment: Here we go: https://godbolt.org/z/1TEYar
Actually constructing and destructing left as an exercise. And it's probably cleaner to have it be size n+1 starting with 0 so the first n offsets are the starting offsets. :-)

Comment: Of course, `std::align` isn't `constexpr`. Here's a nicer version: https://godbolt.org/z/PscPczb66